# is "NULL" is valid for JSON null value in any of the JSON library used for android

Tags: android, json

previously json null was handling properly in app. But suddenly app failed to parse son, as it found NULL instead of null. I want to know, if "NULL" is valid null json object, in any of the json library used for android.

Comment: post your crash log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some info .

1. First of all `null` is keyword in JAVA for indicating object is empty(null).
2. NULL is not keyword in JAVA
3. NULL is valid value for string if it is enclosed by "". eg "NULL"

> I want to know, if "NULL" is valid null json object, in any of the
>   json library used for android.

Answer is **NO**.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,NULL is object in android,added in API level 1.
See the below image,This is screen shot of android studio documentation.
[image]

Comment: NULL is  name of reference. It's declaration is   `public static final Object NULL = null;` it value is ultimately `null`